# Connectedness of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = Z(F) $ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$(over $\mathbb C$) of degree $ d \geq 4$.Then is the following statement " $X$ is always connected " true?

Guess : If $X$ is disconnected, then the two connected components are  hypersurfaces(why?) which does not contain any component of each other and hence by Bezout's theorem   they intersect in atleast $1$ point and hence a contradiction.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: This claim is not entirely correct as presented. You would be best served by writing out a little more detail - what's the definition of a hypersurface, what's it's dimension, what do those dimensions do, etc. so that you may find the gap in your reasoning.

Comment: You've course corrected a little too strongly now - your original claim was very close to being right! There were only at most two values of $n$ where there were issues - and you would be able to prove something much stronger than just what you need here. If you're still struggling, my advice is the same - write out more details. Define a hypersurface - then make your argument about why the connected components are hypersurfaces more specific by interacting with the definition.